# osmnx TypeError in graph_from_polygon after upgrading from 0.5.1 to 0.8.2

Tags: python, osmnx

After finishing my thesis work with osmnx last year I retreated into Python PTSD for a while. But with the release of the 2017 ACS 5-year estimates I have some new data analysis to do. So I updated my osmnx to 0.8.2, did conda update --all -c conda-forge, and fired up my old notebook.

It mostly works but I'm getting an error with the graph_from_polygon function.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-96e1e789c1a5> in <module>()
---> 58     network, network_stats, tract_polygon = load_network(optimal_tracts, utm_crs)
     59 

<ipython-input-56-3036c449a01f> in load_network(opt_tracts, my_crs)
     34 
---> 35     net = ox.core.graph_from_polygon(projected_circle,network_type='bike')
     36 

/Users/tom/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osmnx/core.pyc in 
graph_from_polygon(polygon, network_type, simplify, retain_all, 
truncate_by_edge, name, timeout, memory, max_query_area_size, 
clean_periphery, infrastructure, custom_filter)
   1741    max_query_area_size=max_query_area_size,
   1742    infrastructure=infrastructure, custom_filter=custom_filter)
-> 1743         G_buffered = create_graph(response_jsons, name=name, 
retain_all=True, network_type=network_type)
   1744         G_buffered = truncate_graph_polygon(G_buffered, 
polygon_buffered, retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=truncate_by_edge)
   1745 

/Users/tom/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osmnx/core.pyc in 
create_graph(response_jsons, name, retain_all, network_type)
   1358     # add length (great circle distance between nodes) attribute to each edge to
   1359     # use as weight
-> 1360     if len(G.edges) > 0:
   1361         G = add_edge_lengths(G)
   1362 

TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()
```

Up until this point the packages are still playing together nicely. `projected_circle` appears to be correctly created as a UTM lat-long polygon (epsg:32617, test city Charlotte, NC). Here's the relevant code. (`opt_tracts` is a GeoDataFrame of a set of census tracts).

```
def load_network(opt_tracts,my_crs):    

 tract_poly=opt_tracts.unary_union

 projected_circle,projection = ox.projection.project_geometry(tract_poly,crs={'init': my_crs}, to_latlong=True)

 net = ox.core.graph_from_polygon(projected_circle,network_type='bike')

 net_stats = ox.stats.basic_stats(net,area=8047)

 return (net, net_stats, tract_poly)
```

And here's the console output:

```
Got all network data within polygon from API in 1 request(s) and 0.61 seconds
Creating networkx graph from downloaded OSM data...
Created graph with 11,371 nodes and 22,550 edges in 1.10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of networkx do you have installed?

I would suggest created a new virtual environment, installing OSMnx into it, and then running your jupyter notebook from there, like:

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n OX python=3 osmnx notebook
```

See also: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation

Comment: I'm on:
`networkx                  2.2                        py_1    conda-forge`

I'm really hoping to not have to start clean because there are a bunch of other packages in that environment that my code needs. But I'll give it a shot. 

Also I'm using python 2.7 if that matters.